# Getting streamline for a lid driven cavity flow in openFoam/ParaView

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, openfoam, paraview

I have installed openFoam on Debian GNU/Linux and learning from [official user guide](https://cfd.direct/openfoam/user-guide/). I have a problem with generating streamlines. I am trying to generate streamlines as explained in the [post processing section](https://cfd.direct/openfoam/user-guide/v7-cavity/#x5-130002.1.4) (look at **2.1.4.5 Streamline plots**).

The configuration setup explained is as follows:

> [image]

And the expected output is:

> [image: image2]

But I am getting out put as follows (click on image to zoom):

[image]

Any idea what I am missing?

[Upto this step all things run fine: meshing, `icoFoam`, contours, Vector plots etc.]

Comment: This question seem more appropriate to Paraview's Q&A.

Comment: @nicoguaro which site?

Comment: This is the Q&A for ParaView: https://discourse.paraview.org/

Comment: @nicoguaro ok. Thanks. I'll refer it. Should I delete my question if it's off-topic here?

Comment: That's an option. Or I could close it, so the answer is kept.

Comment: Yes, feel free to close if it's off topic here.

Answer (score 1):

Your initial and end points for the line are the same, thus you only have one line that "emanates" from it. To have multiple streamlines you need multiple seed points. You need to have a vertical line that spans your domain to obtain something similar to what you want.